# Tem alguma forma de rodar software, nativo para 32 bits em 64 bits no CentOS?

Tags: linux, 64-bits, centos

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de rodar o software 32 bits em 64 bits? Se tem, preciso instalar o que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim, mas para isso você precisar ser o root. Caso seja, basta digitar o seguinte comando: `yum install glibc.i686`

Com isso, você poderá rodar software que são compatíveis somente com as versões 32 bits.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: obg mano, funcionou!